# font-weight overwriting my custom font-face (wkhtmltopdf)

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, wkhtmltopdf

I use @font-face on my website for my users to get their own custom font.
On internet everything works fine. (Don't pay attention to the line-height, it's not an issue.)
[image]

But when I export in pdf I get this
[image]

I've made some tests and I realized it's due to my inherit 'font-weight:400'
[image]

If I change the value for `'font-weight:900'` it exports well.

The problem I have is webpages are generated dynamically and I can't predict the font-weight of the user uploaded font.

Is there a way to remove the font-weight attribute in order to not interfere with the uploaded @font-face ?

I've tried `'font-weight:unset !important'` but without success...

Comment: You may be misunderstanding how @font-face rules work: what you do with `@font-face` is that you are teaching the CSS engine what it should be doing when it sees a combination of font-family plus {font-weight, font-style, ...}. Irrespective of the font's actual look, if you declare a `@font-face` rule and say "when you see family X, with weight 100, and style normal, use source myfont-italic-superbold.woff", then any element with a class that says to use `font-family: X; font-weight: 100; font-style: normal;` will use `myfont-itaic-superbold.woff`.

Comment: So: if you have a url to the user's uploaded font, declare an `@font-face` rule that gives it a unique font family name, don't specify any other property, and then render the element that should use the font with the element's font-family set to that unique name

Comment: thanks mike, it's useful to understand that

Answer (score 0):

Try `font-weight:normal;`. That typically works for me.

Comment: not working. I still get 'font-weight:400' on my style inspector and the rendering doesn't works as well :/

Comment: Do you have a link?